# Need help in Group by in DB2

Tags: group-by, db2

This is Parent_Child table.

```
PARENT  CHILD   EFF_DATE
22716   2528    3/8/2011
22716   5696    3/8/2011
22716   3698    3/8/2011
22716   5698    3/18/2010
37091   4569    10/22/2013
37091   6931    9/17/2014
```

Query result should look like this:

```
PARENT  CHILD   EFF_DATE
22716   2528    3/8/2011
22716   5696    3/8/2011
22716   3698    3/8/2011
37091   6931    9/17/2014
```

Query tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PARENT,P.CHILD,C.MAX_DATE
FROM parent_child P
INNER JOIN
(SELECT CHILD,MAX(EFF_DT) AS MAX_DATE 
FROM parent_child
GROUP BY CHILD) C
ON P.CHILD=C.CHILD AND P.EFF_DT=C.MAX_DATE
ORDER BY P.PARENT
```

But I end up getting both the values of parent 37091.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: can you create an sqlfiddle ?

Comment: here is the fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/603e0/1

Comment: @amdixon above is the fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes required**

> - change inner query to group on parent instead of child
> - change join condition to match on parent

**query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PARENT,P.CHILD,C.MAX_DATE
  FROM parent_child P
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT PARENT,MAX(EFF_DT) AS MAX_DATE 
      FROM parent_child
      GROUP BY PARENT) C
  ON  P.PARENT=C.PARENT
  AND P.EFF_DT=C.MAX_DATE
  ORDER BY P.PARENT
;
```

**output**

> ```
> PARENT    CHILD   MAX_DATE
> 22716     2528    March, 08 2011 00:00:00
> 22716     5696    March, 08 2011 00:00:00
> 22716     3698    March, 08 2011 00:00:00
> 37091     6931    September, 17 2014 00:00:00
> ```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60998/1)